# Help to prove fact about quintic and galois theory?

Tags: galois-theory

Consider $f = 2x^5 - 10x +5 \in Q[x]$. Let $L/Q$ be a splitting field of f. Show that $Gal(L/Q)$ injects as a subgroup of $S_5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Show that every automorphism must permute the roots of $f$, and that an automorphism is completely determined by where it sends the roots.

Comment: Why does this make subgroup of $S_5$? Why not $A_5$? or other group?

Comment: @arithmetic Because $S_5$ is the group of permutations of sets with five elements. And $A_5$ is a subgroup of $S_5$, so any subgroup of $A_5$ is obviously a subgroup of $S_5$.